# Android to Unity cross platform conversion

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have received the source code for an android program that was made in unity.
Is it possible to convert the program from an android source code back to unity?

Comment: You got Unity and want to convert it to Unity? What?

Comment: nono i received the game in android source code. is it possible to convert it back to unity source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to convert a Java file into a workable Unity project. 
There are tools to decompile `APK` files like [APKTool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) or [Android APK Decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) but if you want the entire project including all build files then I don't think it is possible.
Unity deliberately protects your assets for you when you compile a project into a runnable file, which is a good thing for developers who don't want their assets used by others.

Comment: i have the source code for the application. the application was originally made in unity and was converted to android for me is it possible to convert it back to unity?

Comment: Do you mean it was converted to Java code?

Comment: yes it was converted into java code so that is is possible for it to be imported into eclipse. is it possible to convert it back to unity ?

Comment: If you want to convert the entire thing into a Unity project you can then edit and recompile then I don't think you can.

Comment: oh icic so the only way is to obtain the source file from the original developer

Comment: Unless they have shared it with full access permission, then yes.